# Get XML values using PowerShell

Tags: xml, powershell

I am trying to fetch the values for `<Attribute>`, `<Condition>` and `<Group>` tags.
There can be multiple `<Attribute>` tags, so I need to fetch the values separately.

I am trying to prepare a condition out the above tags. Something like below.

```
if (HireType -eq 'KI' -and HireType1 = 'KI1' ){
  $Groups = 'A,B,C'
}
```

I tried to write the code with the hep of ChildNodes, but it is merging the texts if there are multiple  tags.

**XML**

```
<UserData>
    <FilterCriteria>
    </FilterCriteria>
    <GroupCriteria>
        <Criteria>
           <Attributes>
              <Attribute>
                 <AttrName>HireType</AttrName>
                 <AttrValue>KI</AttrValue>
              </Attribute>
              <Attribute>
                 <AttrName>HireType1</AttrName>
                 <AttrValue>KI1</AttrValue>
              </Attribute>
              <Condition>and</Condition>
              <Groups>A,B,C</Groups>
           </Attributes>
        </Criteria>
    </GroupCriteria>
</UserData>
```

***Code***

```
[xml] $xml = Get-Content -Path C:\Users\Arun\Desktop\UserData.xml


$xml.UserData.GroupCriteria | foreach {
  $_.Criteria | foreach {
    $_.Attributes | foreach {
          $_.ChildNodes | % {
            $Name = $_.Name
            $Value = $_.InnerText
              write-host "$Name : $Value"
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

**Output**

```
Attribute : HireTypeKI
Attribute : HireType1KI1
Condition : and
Groups : A,B,C
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the `<Attribute>` tags are structured differently, you'll need to handle those different from the others:

```
foreach ($node in $xml.UserData.GroupCriteria.Criteria.Attributes.ChildNodes) {
    switch ($node.Name) {
        'Attribute' {
            $Name = $node.AttrName
            $Value = $node.AttrValue
        }
        default {
            $Name = $node.Name
            $Value = $node.InnerText
        }
    }
    Write-Host "$Name : $Value"
}
```